# url decode exception - c#

Tags: c#

I have some URL encoded data in a db (sql server 2005) which I decode to parse it. I use:

```
Uri.UnescapeDataString
```

sometimes I get:

{"Invalid URI: There is an invalid sequence in the string."}

what invalid sequences do I have to look out for you reckon?

Thanks.

Christian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` method instead?

Answer (score 1):

As for the "why", perhaps you were running into the .NET 4.0/4.5 issue listed here? [Uri.UnescapeDataString fails on different computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236048/uri-unescapedatastring-fails-on-different-computer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
string decodedUrl = Server.UrlDecode("your-url");
```

Answer (score 0):

It may possible that your string contain HexEncoded Parameters.

Can you please provide sample string that cause this  error.

Thanks,
Jinal.