# Uri.UnescapeDataString fails on different computer

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, uri

On my dev computer everything was working fine and dandy but when I tested the program on a different Windows7 computer I was getting a `System.UriFormatException`: *Invalid URI: There is an invalid sequence in the string.* On the following code: `Uri.UnescapeDataString(section);`

At first I thought the second computer was receiving different data from the dev pc, so I copied the html string that was failing to a file and reduced my code to this:

```
static void Err(string s){/*Picked up by external logging*/}

private static void GetValue()
{
    try
    {
        var html = File.ReadAllText("ld.txt");

        //Retrieve section we want
        var section = Regex.Match(
            html,
            "etc_etc(.*): ",
            RegexOptions.Singleline)
                                .Groups[1].ToString();

        Uri.UnescapeDataString(section);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Err(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Works fine on the dev pc, but the second computer receives the exception again. They're both loading the exact same html from the exact same `ld.txt` file and then doing the exact same thing with it.. and both PC's are x64 Win7. What gives?

Comment: .NET version and patches? It is possible that one is patched and the other is not... And what is the line in the ld.txt that produces the error?

Comment: Did not check for that, but application is built with 4.0. I'll see if updating helps (if there are any.)

Comment: Could it be a text encoding issue? One computer has a different default text encoding than the other? Have you verified that the string `section` on computer 1 is exactly the same as the `section` on computer 2? Both running the same version of .NET?

Comment: @JimMischel According to notepad++ compare plugin the section matches for both PC's.

Comment: Using notepad++ probably won't identify a problem if it's a text encoding issue in the application. You're probably better off inspecting the string with your own two eyes.

Comment: @Jim The positive result from said plugin + the fact that both strings have the exact same length should be validation enough I think ^^

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.Uri.ToString behaviour change after VS2012 install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004214/system-uri-tostring-behaviour-change-after-vs2012-install)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UnescapeDataString appears to have changed between CLR 4.0 and 4.5

I can reproduce this on two machines with different versions of .Net installed (even though compiled to target .Net 4.0).

Do you perhaps have VS 2012 on your dev machine (and therefore .Net 4.5) and just .Net 4 on the other computer?

This code throws an exception on .Net 4.0, passes on .Net 4.5

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CLR version: " + Environment.Version);
        Console.WriteLine(Uri.UnescapeDataString("%"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering so long after the fact. I do indeed have vs2012 on my dev machine and not on the other computer so I'm going to go ahead and assume that's what caused it.

Comment: You're welcome. I hit the same issue so posted this here for the greater good :)

Comment: This was very helpful. In fact I only needed to install [.Net Framework 4.5.1 Developer Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40772) and this issue was resolved. Everything including configurations, double escaping etc. were similar still this issue wasn't going. Your solution did it. Thanks!