# Uri.UnescapeDataString("%") error Invalid URI: There is an invalid sequence in the string in some different computers

Tags: c#, uri, decode

when using `Uri.UnescapeDataString("%")` in computer with clr version 4.0.30319.17929
there is no error
but in other computers same .net framework installed but minor version is differrent 4.0.30319.1 or
4.0.30319.1026 or 4.0.30319.18444

get error : Invalid URI: There is an invalid sequence in the string.

what should I do for that?

using some other command or

forcing same version(how?) or

installing a path or file for .net framework on computers that have error?

Comment: A similar question has been answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15236048/uri-unescapedatastring-fails-on-different-computer
Kind regards, Rob